# AS3 - Removing the object after being hit by another object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am creating a simple game that when the object hit the coin, then the score will increment and the coin will be gone.....

I have this code, the food1 is the one that will be gone after being hit, and the scoreOutput is the instance name of the dynamic text.

```
if(player.hitTestObject(food1)){
    removeChild(food1);
    score += 10;
    scoreOutput.text = String(score);
}
```

I got this error

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at game_fla::MainTimeline/moveObject()
```

maybe because i used the remove child, but i really dont have an idea on how to remove that object from the stage since im not familiar with actionscripting...

Any suggestion on how could I do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: food1 where was added? on stage? right?

Comment: try: food1.parent.removeChild( food1 ); the element you try to remove is not child of »this«, in this case the timeline itself

Comment: @bitmapdata.com yes.... i put it already before the game begins

Comment: @philipp after i put that, the player is not moving after it hits the object and the error says "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: @Katherine you try to access the »food1« object elsewhere after it is removed from the display list. perhaps food1.visible = false can server as deletion as well

Comment: @philipp the food1.visible = false works well, but the score keeps on incrementing when the player is in the position of the food1

Comment: @Katherine from your question and problem I conclude that you are a programming beginner. If I can give you a piece of advice: Learn what references, or Pointers are. The problems you have are possibly simple but with your question you try to cure symptoms, if you want to heal than spent a bit more time in learning. Coding a flash game in the timeline in asking for headache and as beginner perhaps a bit too much for the start.

Comment: @philipp not really a programming beginner, but in action scripting yes im a beginner with that. btw thanks

Comment: @Katherine Try to use a document class and use as3 classes for the Objects that displayed in your game. You can link custom classes to symbols in the library and there you can implement the delete() remove() logic and keep track on the elements that are actually in the display list. Furthermore you can use type checking to determine whether a click happened over targets you are interested in and much more stuff that will make development easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you're if block multiple call. any reason.

so, change a this code.

```
if(player.hitTestObject(food1))
{
    if(stage.contains(food1))
        removeChild(food1);

    score += 10;
    scoreOutput.text = String(score);
}
```

and check a look at the full code.

Comment: Thanks, this code worked after i enclosed the remaining code in braces in that if(stage.contains(food1)) .... thanks for that :)